# Interpolate in python using np.interp over two 1D arrays: error ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading some csv files with radiosondes data (e.g. height, temperature,rh etc.).
I want to interpolate these data into different altitudes using np.interp in python.

Here is my code:

```
#Read multiple csv files - around 100

path = '/data/eioanni/Python_Script/treated_PAFA/' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = ",",skiprows=3,index_col=None, header=None)

    li.append(df)


#Concatenate all data into one DataFrame

big_frame = pd.concat(li,axis=0)

height = big_frame[big_frame.columns[1]]

height = height.as_matrix()

height = np.array(height)

temp   = big_frame[big_frame.columns[2]]

temp = temp.as_matrix()

temp = np.array(temp)

#convert C to K

temp = temp + 273.15

rh     = big_frame[big_frame.columns[4]]

rh = rh.as_matrix()

ws     = big_frame[big_frame.columns[7]]

ws = ws.as_matrix()

#convert knot to m/s

ws = ws/1.944


#Shape temp,height etc 1D - (24900,)
#height is increasing per day. 

temperature_134m = np.zeros_like(temp[0])


for kk in np.arange(temp.shape[0]):

     temper_temp = np.array(temp[kk])

     print temper_temp #check 1st value (here 264K)

     height_temp = height[kk]

     print height_temp #check 1st value (here 134m)

     temperature_134[kk] = np.interp(140., height_temp,temper_temp)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
return interp_func([x], xp, fp, left, right).item()
```

> ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

I can interpolate the observations when I am reading one file the time using `np.interp` without any problem.

Any suggestions how to resolve this? Shall I change interpolation method or read and process all the files/data in a different way?

Comment: Look at `np.shape([x])`.  Is that what you intend?  How does it compare with the argument in the case(s) that works?

Comment: @hpaulj The x in cases that the code works is increasing, while in that case of multiple files x is increasing (1st file), then 2nd file is attached so x decreased before start increasing once again etc.. x is 1D in any case. I just cannot think of a way to make it run..

Comment: did you `print(np.shape([x]))`?

Comment: @hpaulj in the for loop gives () ...

Comment: that's a 0d array, not the needed 1d